# div object flashing repeatedly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i tried to create a fade-in/out effect for one of my divs but the fade-in effect on its own was working fine but when coupled with the fade-out effect, it makes the whole div continue to flash in the viewport area. 
take a look at the code:

```
    hover.addEventListener('mouseover',function () {$('#cpanel').fadeIn("slow");/*Core.addClass(cpanel,"on");*/},false);
    hover.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {$('#cpanel').fadeOut("slow");/*Core.removeClass(cpanel,"on");*/},false);
```

the cursor seems to be loosing focus of the object since it fades-in and fades-out repeatedly.
can someone please help?

edit: the commented out part is the method i used before i implemented the jquery. also Core is another library i am using. cpanel is the div i want to fade-in/out.

as requested, the cpanel HTML:

```
<div id="cpanel">
            <div class="box"  name="prevImg"><a href="#" id="prevImg"><img class='text' src="nav-prev.gif"/></a></div>
            <div class="box"  name="zoom"><a href="#" id="Zoom"><img class='text' src="nav-zoom.gif"/></a></div>
            <div class="box"  name="back"><a href="#" id="Back"><img class='text' src="nav-home.gif"/></a></div>
            <div class="box"  name="nextImg"><a href="#" id="nextImg"><img class='text' src="nav-next.gif"/></a></div>  
        </div>
```

the hover div is generated through DOM. it is a hidden div which i have used just to make sure the hover happens in the middle of the display container.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the hover method.

```
$('your item').hover(function(){$("#cpanel").fadeIn("slow")},function(){$("#cpanel").fadeOut("slow");});
```

The hover method takes two functions - one is activated on mouse in, the other on mouse out.

See [the jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) for more information.

Comment: i am not able to get it to work. when i use the above statement, when i mouseovr the reqd area, nothing happens.

Comment: $(this).fadeIn("#cpanel") is incorrect. fadeIn takes a speed setting and a callback not a selector

Comment: also the above will never work as youll never be able to hove something that has been faded out.I think he meant....
$('your item').hover(function(){$("#cpanel").fadeIn("slow")},function(){$("#cpanel").fadeOut("slow");});